¿porqué no me funciona una simple sentencia LET en XQUERY?
Partiendo de este XML
<ies>
    <modulos>
        <modulo id="0228">
            <nombre>Aplicaciones web</nombre>
            <curso>2</curso>
            <horasSemanales>4</horasSemanales>
            <ciclo>SMR</ciclo>
        </modulo>
        <modulo id="0372">
            <nombre>Gestión de bases de datos</nombre>
            <curso>1</curso>
            <horasSemanales>5</horasSemanales>
            <ciclo>ASIR</ciclo>
        </modulo>
        <modulo id="0373">
            <nombre>Lenguajes de marcas y sistemas de gestión de información</nombre>
            <curso>1</curso>
            <horasSemanales>3</horasSemanales>
            <ciclo>ASIR</ciclo>
            <ciclo>DAW</ciclo>
        </modulo>
            <modulo id="0376">
            <nombre>Implantación de aplicaciones web</nombre>
            <curso>2</curso>
            <horasSemanales>5</horasSemanales>
            <ciclo>ASIR</ciclo>
        </modulo>
    </modulos>
</ies>

Quiero realizar una consulta xquery que son todos lo módulos que pertenecen al ciclo ASIR
y la realizo de la siguiente forma.
let $asir := doc("modulos_informatica.xml")//modulo
where $asir/ciclo = "ASIR"
return $asir

El problema es que me devuelve TODOS los módulos y no me filtra aquellos que pertenecen al ciclo ASIR.
Si alguien pudiera ayudarme le estaré eternamente agradecido.
Saludos.

"xml" y "xquery"

Podrías utilizar simplemente
doc("modulos_informatica.xml")//modulo[ciclo = "ASIR"]

o deberías utilizar for y not let
for $modulo in doc("modulos_informatica.xml")//modulo
where $modulo/ciclo = "ASIR"
return $modulo

Ejemplo en línea.
